# How do you turn off graphic content in COD BO3?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I would like to turn off explicit language content and all blood and gore. Is this possible?

Comment: You are, of course, entitled to experience the game you bought in any such way as you see fit but may i ask why would you want this?

Comment: maybe it's a parent wanting this....

Answer (score 1):

To turn off graphic content (gore, etc.) go to the pause menu. From there, proceed to the "Options" section of the menu, and select "Content Filter." After you've done that, simply disable "Graphic Content." You cannot, however, disable explicit language in the game. Your best bet would be to simply mute the game entirely or just use subtitles with the speech volume muted.